# Angular lazy loading components and bindings

Tags: angular, binding, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement lazy loading on my web app under Angular 9.

It is already up and running but the bundle is too big to first load.

So when I try to do the lazy loading components, all my bindings stop to work.

I get that error :

```
ERROR in src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.ts:22:14 - error NG6007: The Component 'FuncViewComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.

22 export class FuncViewComponent implements OnInit {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/vitrine.module.ts:8:18
    8   declarations: [FuncViewComponent]
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'FuncViewComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'VitrineModule'.
  src/app/app.module.ts:83:5
    83     FuncViewComponent,
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'FuncViewComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule'.
src/app/vitrine.module.ts:8:18 - error NG6001: The class 'FuncViewComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'VitrineModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

8   declarations: [FuncViewComponent]
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.ts:22:14
    22 export class FuncViewComponent implements OnInit {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'FuncViewComponent' is declared here.
src/app/app.module.ts:83:5 - error NG6001: The class 'FuncViewComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove 
it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

83     FuncViewComponent,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.ts:22:14
    22 export class FuncViewComponent implements OnInit {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'FuncViewComponent' is declared here. "
```

or that one when I remove the declaration in the app.module.ts

```
   ERROR in src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.ts:22:14 - error NG6007: The Component 'FuncViewComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.

22 export class FuncViewComponent implements OnInit {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/vitrine.module.ts:8:18
    8   declarations: [FuncViewComponent]
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'FuncViewComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'VitrineModule'.
  src/app/app.module.ts:83:5
    83     FuncViewComponent,
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'FuncViewComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule'.
src/app/vitrine.module.ts:8:18 - error NG6001: The class 'FuncViewComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'VitrineModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

8   declarations: [FuncViewComponent]
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.ts:22:14
    22 export class FuncViewComponent implements OnInit {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'FuncViewComponent' is declared here.
```

My app is a main page which contain 3 sub sections which are themselves components which are reused on the others pages (the ones I want to lazy load). And I serve the data from firebase to those 3 sub sections through bindings.

But those bindings are not working once I move the pages on the secondary routing module.

So the CLI is saying I can't declare the components on both NgModule (the main and the lazy one) but those bindings are used by the main page (which should not lazy load obviously). How can I resolve this issue ?

This is the app-routing.module.ts

```
  export const appRouteList: Routes = [
{
    path: 'votre-logiciel-de-secrétariat', component: MainViewComponent, data: {
        title: 'Votre Logiciel de Secrétariat'
    }
},
{
    path: 'les-fonctionnalites-du-logiciel', loadChildren: () => import('./vitrine.module').then(m => m.VitrineModule)
},
{
    path: 'application-mobile-tempora', component: AppmobileComponent, data: {
        title: 'Application Mobile Tempora'
    }
},
```

This is my vitrine-routing.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
    import { FuncViewComponent } from './modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component';


    const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'les-fonctionnalites-du-logiciel', component: FuncViewComponent, data: {
      title: 'La solution logiciel pour les centres d\'appels et les structures médicales'
    }
  }
    ];

    @NgModule({
exports: [RouterModule],
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
     })
    export class VitrineRoutingModule { }
```

and here the vitrine.module.ts

```
   import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
   import { VitrineRoutingModule } from './vitrine-routing.module';
   import { FuncViewComponent } from './modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component';

   @NgModule({
imports: [VitrineRoutingModule],
declarations: [FuncViewComponent]
   })
   export class VitrineModule { }
```

I did try to change the path in app-routing-module to

```
      path: 'les-fonctionnalites-du-logiciel', loadChildren: () => import('./vitrine-routing.module').then(m => m.VitrineRoutingModule)
```

That way the compiler does not return an error, but my page does not load.

So I followed step by step (or so I thought :p) the Angular Tutorial but now, i get the following error:

```
     ERROR in src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view-routing.module.ts:3:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component'.

     3 import { FuncViewComponent } from './modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.module.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"C:/site-angular-tempora/site-tempora/src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view-routing.module"' has no exported 
  member 'FuncViewRoutingModule'.

  2 import { FuncViewRoutingModule } from './func-view-routing.module';
```

After that I redid the import of the component, and it seems to go well but I get this error related to the bindings I am talking about at the start of my quite long post:

```
43             <app-net-gain [netGain]="netGain"></app-net-gain>
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.ts:19:16
    19   templateUrl: './func-view.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FuncViewComponent.
src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.html:43:27 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'netGain' since it isn't a known property of 'app-net-gain'.
1. If 'app-net-gain' is an Angular component and it has 'netGain' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-net-gain' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

43             <app-net-gain [netGain]="netGain"></app-net-gain>
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modules/vitrine/func-view/func-view.component.ts:19:16
    19   templateUrl: './func-view.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FuncViewComponent.
```

And if I declare those components in that module, it will say that they are declared in 2 NgModule and that won't do. I need those components on that page but also on the main page and even on some others page of the web site.

From what I could gather from left and right, it seems that you can't data bind from a component to a lazyloaded component. If anyone can confirm ?

Cheers

Comment: Without seeing some code, I think this will be a hard one to debug from your description - can you provide a link to code, or a stackblitz running the code?

Comment: You are right, I added some code to help visualize

Comment: @Specialka import { FuncViewComponent } from './modules looks suspicious. Component should be placed inside of single module. You can export components from module and use in other modules

Comment: @Specialka binding error means 'app-net-gain' is invisible for func-view.component. maybe you can try use component from other module without properly export/import